# Proof of Circuit-Sat to Nand-Sat polynomial time many–one reducibility

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, satisfiability, circuits

Given a gate called **Nand** with the following truth table:

```
 A | B | A Nand B
------------------
 0 | 0 |    1
 0 | 1 |    1
 1 | 0 |    1
 1 | 1 |    0
```

We can define a circuit satisfiability problem where only Nand gates are allowed:

> $\mathrm{Nand\text{-}Sat}$:
>
> *Input*: A Boolean circuit $C$ with $m$ inputs $(P_{1},P_{2}\ldots,P_{m})$ such that all gates are Nand gates.
>
> *Question*: Is there a Boolean assignment to the inputs of $C$ such that the output of $C$ is $1$?

I would like to show that $\mathrm{Circuit\text{-}Sat} \leq_{P} \mathrm{Nand\text{-}Sat}$. Where $\mathrm{Circuit\text{-}Sat}$ is the normal circuit satisfiability problem:

> $\mathrm{Circuit\text{-}Sat}$:
>
> *Input*: A Boolean circuit $C$ with $m$ inputs $(P_{1},P_{2}\ldots,P_{m})$.
>
> *Question*: Is there a Boolean assignment to the inputs of $C$ such that the output of $C$ is $1$?

My question is do I have to create a function that translate AND,OR,NOT gates into Nand gates?

Comment: You don't have to, but that would be a good way to go.

Comment: what's the other option ? thanks

Comment: @mike10101 There isn't really another option, if you can construct the reduction, then you have to turn a normal Boolean circuit into a Nyet circuit, so all the gates, one way or another, end up encoded as Nyet gates. Working out how to turn the gates _individually_ into Nyet gates is the easiest way. Try converting the NOT gate first - the conversion is "simple" (in the "not complicated" sense).

Comment: @LukeMathieson thanks ! here is what i did for the "Not" part (A and A) Or (A and notA) Or (notA and A)

Comment: @mike10101 You want to go a slightly different route; try making a Not gate using only Nyet gates (a big hint is that you can do it with a single Nyet gate).

Comment: @LukeMathieson  Not A = A Nyet A

Comment: @mike10101, now you just need to do the same for the other two gates, and you're basically done.

Answer (score 0):

not A = A nand A
A Or B = (A nand A) nand (B nand B)
A and A = (A nand B) nand (A nand B)